# How to consume one day's old dataset in oozie coordinator

Tags: hadoop, dataset, workflow, oozie

I am looking for the correct way to achieve the following:

**Scenario:**

1. Connectors are feeding the data and it is getting store at path `/data/2015/09/15/csvfile.csv` in hdfs. (storing day wise)
2. My coordinator job is running on 2015-09-15T23:59 at the end of the day and consuming the data of that day which from above mentioned path and store it into hive table under partition `day = 16`.

Basically I want to have each partition holds the last day data if data is available and if data is not available then there should not be partition created.

**For Example**
collected data of 15th should store into partitions 16 similarly 
16th data into 17th partitions and so on.

Suppose the feeding is started form `2015-09-15T00:00` till `2015-09-16T00:00` that is full one day and stored at path `/data/2015/09/15/file.csv`

The coordinator job getting materialized at `2015-09-15T23:59` and it should consume the data from `/data/2015/09/15/file.csv` path and pass it to coordinator action as input.

Following are the oozie coordinator file which I have used which is running but its not giving expected output when there is no data available for particular day to consume by coordinator.

**Coordinator xml File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coordinator-app name="App" frequency=1440 start=2015-09-15T23:59Z end=2015-09-30T23:59Z timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4">
  <datasets>
    <dataset name="logs" frequency=1440 initial-instance=2015-09-15T23:59Z timezone="UTC">
        <uri-template>${DataPath}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</uri-template>
        <done-flag>file.csv</done-flag>
    </dataset>
  </datasets>
  <input-events>
    <data-in name="isready_logs" dataset="logs">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
  </input-events>
  <action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${ApplicationPath}/log_wf.xml</app-path>
      <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>currentday</name>
                <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), 1, 'DAY'), 'dd')}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>currentmonth</name>
                <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(), 'MM')}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>currentyear</name>
                <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(), 'yyyy')}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>input</name>
              <value>${coord:dataIn('isready_logs')}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>ScriptPath</name>
                <value>${ApplicationPath}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>XmlPath</name>
                <value>${ApplicationPath}</value>
            </property>
      </configuration>
    </workflow>
  </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Can you guide me that am i configuring the coordinator with correct values or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @abhishek. Thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 0):

You have an offset of plus one day but only on the currentday and not on currentyear or currentmonth.

This means that for a coordinator job materialized at `2015-09-15T23:59` the date will be `2015-09-16`. But for a coordinator job materialized at `2015-12-31T23:59` the date will be 2015-12-01`

If you wanted to use an offset, you should add that offset to month and year, or else it would calculate the wrong date in the end of the month and in the end of the year.

```
<value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), 1, 'DAY'), 'dd')}</value>
...
<value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), 1, 'DAY'), 'MM')}</value>
...
<value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), 1, 'DAY'), 'yyyy')}</value>
```